# Jquery reorder html element

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have 5 html elements

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image5.jpg" /></a>
```

I want to reorder to

```
<a href="#"><img src="image5.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
```

How can I achieve this with jquery (no plugins if possible).

Thanks

Comment: The first ones seem better ordered to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('img').last().parent().insertBefore($('img').first().parent());
```

Though with *no* information regarding the specific criteria for their being reordered, it's hard to offer a specifically-useful solution.

The above assumes that you want to reorder the elements based on the image element (since that's the one that appears most-obviously indexed/numbered), however to use the `a` instead:

```
$('a').last().insertBefore($(this).prevAll(':last'));
```

Comment: why not use a instead of img??

Comment: Because an `a` could be anywhere on the page. However, he could use a class *for* the `a` to make sure that the correct anchor is associated with the correct image. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 6):

Supposing you have this HTML  :

```
 <div id=parent>
   <a href="#"><img src="image5.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
```

And you want to order by the src of the images, then you can do this :

```
function compareStrings(a,b) {
  if (a>b) return 1;
  else if (a<b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
$('#parent').append($('a').detach().sort(function(a,b){
  return compareStrings($('img',a).attr('src'), $('img',b).attr('src'));
}));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ogudox/2/)

Comment: nice, generalises to other sort orders well

Answer (score 1):

I found this code to work very well (not mine):
blogpost: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/
source: http://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/sortElements/

Example: (paraphrased from the blog)

```
<ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Include library, then run this:

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Result:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sort elements with a predicate basically. This is absolutely perfect. Thanks!